# JWPlayer in React-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to integrate JWPlayer in react native by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jw-media-player I have done the android and iOS setup correctly but still when running the application it's loads with empty screen. Here is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import JWPlayer from 'react-native-jw-media-player';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <JWPlayer
    ref={p => (this.JWPlayer = p)}
    style={{width: 320, height: 240}}
    file='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'

  />
        </View>

    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  player: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add styles.player class in JWPlayerstyle

```
  <JWPlayerstyle={styles.player} />
```

or use

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <JWPlayer
    style={styles.player}
    autostart={false}
    file={'https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8'}
    onBeforePlay={() => this.onBeforePlay()}
    onPlay={() => this.onPlay()}
    onPlayerError={e => this.onPlayerError(e)}
    onBuffer={() => this.onBuffer()}
    onTime={time => this.onTime(time)}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: I tried, but that too did not worked. Do I need to add any API key in xcode.?

Comment: No error at all. It is displaying only blank screen.

Comment: Have you restart the app

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled and re-installed the application

Comment: Have you add api keys?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206705/discussion-between-ankush-kumar-and-vicky-keshri).

Comment: I did not found any solution on chat. Anybody who about this issue, please reply.

Comment: Have you include jwplayer settings.gradle file ?

Comment: How can we do that.?

Comment: Please do accordingly https://github.com/nulleof/react-native-jwplayer

Comment: I am trying with that, but screen is empty. Can we do hangout call and share the screen,  if this help. vicky.pes.2014@gmail.com

Comment: I am waiting, I have done all same. However, unable to understand JWPlayerKey in info.plist

Comment: I am still waiting

Comment: @vickykeshri are you still waiting?

Comment: we switched to some other library. But still any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: @vickykeshri did you find any solution for playing jw videos in ios (react-native ) Working find on android. Can you suggest some other player that can play jw videos on ios.

Comment: @HarishJangra Nope, I didn't get any solution on this but you can use:  react-native-video-player.